# Custom Search API limitations

Tags: android, google-search, google-search-api

I am working on an Android app. When the user opens my app I need to make 2/3 requests to Google Search API. In according with the documentation 100 requests/day are free and the registration on Google Cloud is not required. (anonymous requests)

It's not clear if 100 requests/day are per unique user or per app.

If they are per app it means I can have just 30/50 users.
If they are per single user, I don't have any problem.

Does anyone know more about it?

Answer (score 1):

It is clear from their [pricing section](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview#pricing) that they mean 100 search queries per day for free per API key. So one user of your app could technically use all of these up by himself.

So if you're anticipating more than 100 queries from all users of your app per day then you will need to figure out how to handle the pricing.